# How to normalize an ndarray of matrices, such that each matrix equals itself divided by its l-2 norm?

Tags: python, numpy, classification, normalization

So I have a an ndarray of shape (60000, 1, 28, 28) which is essentially 60000 28x28 matrices. They represent pixel values and I need to normalize each image by its l-2 norm. Essentially, I have to divide each 28x28 matrix by its own l-2 norm.

Any suggestions as to how I can do this efficiently without looping through the entire array?

I tried the following code but it didn't seem to work:

```
norms = np.linalg.norm(training_data, ord=2, axis=0)
normalized_training_data = training_data / norms
```

but I just got a numch of 0s and NaNs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the right axes to compute the norm over:

```
norms = np.linalg.norm(training_data, ord=2, axis=(2, 3))
```

Comment: I did this and tried to reshape the resulting norms array to (60000, 1, 1) so that I can element wise divide the two ndarrays. However, this does not work and my kernel dies. I tried running it separately on terminal too and it didnt produce an output. Any reason why the division might not be occurring?

Comment: Sounds like it might be performing an outer division over the two axes of length 1, which would result in an array too large to allocate. Try to make the shape of both arrays equal, or flatten one of them.